# Mi archivo Ajax no recibe respuesta del PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Buen dia colegas, estoy intentando realizar un registro de usuario con ajax y php, el problema viene en que el php genera la informacion pero el ajax no recibe la respuesta por lo que no entra en una condicion que tengo declarado, alguien pudiera revisar donde esta el error, ya que solo me imprime el resultado en consola pero no realiza la accion de la condicion

adjunto codigos

Archivo del Ajax

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

$('#form-registro').on('submit', function(e){
    
    e.preventDefault();

    var datos = $('#form-registro').serializeArray();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: datos,
        url: 'services/newUser.php',
        dataType: 'json',
         success:function (data){
             console.log(data);
            if(data.respuesta === "exitoso"){
                Swal.fire(
                    'registro correcto!',
                    'Bienvenid@  !!',
                    'success'
                  )
                  setTimeout(function(){
                      window.location.href = "index.php";
                  }, 20);
            }
            else{
                alert("Hubo un error");
            }
            
           }
    });
    

});
```

});

Archivo PHP donde genera la respuesta

```
<?php

include '../database/db.config.php';

if(isset($_POST['registro'])){
    $correo = $_POST['correo'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    if($_POST['registro'] == "nuevo"){
        $nombre = $_POST['nombre']; 
        $apellido = $_POST['apellido'];
        $telefono = $_POST['telefono']; 
        try{//aqui inserta el nuevo registro en la tabla correspondiente evitando sql injection
            $stmt = $conex->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios(nombre,apellido,correoElectro,telefono, pass ) values (?,?,?,?,?)");//manda 0 como inactivo el usuario
            $stmt->bind_param("sssss", $nombre, $apellido, $correo,$telefono, $password);
            $stmt->execute();
            $id_registro = $stmt->insert_id;
            if($id_registro > 0){
                $respuesta = array(
                    'respuesta' => "exitoso",
                    'idusuario' => $id_registro
                );
            }else{
                $respuesta = array(
                    'respuesta' => 'fallo',
                    // 'idusuario' => $id_registro
                );
            }
            

            $stmt->close();
            $conex->close();
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "error ".$e->getMessage();
        }
    }
    die(json_encode($respuesta));
}

?>
```

agradezco la ayuda

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrarnos lo que imprime en consola? Por cierto, no necesitas hacer parse si indicas un `dataType: 'json'` por tanto, esto sobra: `var resultado = JSON.parse(data);` puedes usar `data` directamente, pues será un JSON. Aunque falta uniformidad en PHP. En la parte del `catch` deberías emitir un json, algo así: `echo json_encode( array( 'respuesta'=>'fallo', 'msg'=>$e->getMessage() ) );`

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano no me imprime nada en consola sin embargo en el viewport me imprime esto

Comment: {"respuesta":"exitoso","idusuario":59}

Comment: ¿Quitaste esto: `var resultado = JSON.parse(data);` y estás probando así: **`if(data.respuesta === 'exitoso'){`** ? Como dije antes, `data` debe ser un JSON, porque lo indicaste en el parámetro `dataType` de la petición Ajax, de modo que no necesitas aplicar `JSON.parse()` a `data`.

Comment: Asi es ya corregi como sugirio y sigue realizando la misma accion, alguna idea mas?

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] para ver cómo tienes el código Javascript ahora. Debería funcionar. Aunque no sé por qué dices que no ves nada en consola y sí en el viewport ¿? ¿A qué te refieres con el *viewport*?

Comment: ¿No será que la página se recarga y no alcanzas a ver si se muestra o no la alerta? Quita o comenta la función para recargar (`setTimeout()`).

Comment: En ese caso me llevaria al login pero no lo realiza, y en cuanto al viewport quiero decir que en html me imprime esto:

Comment: {"respuesta":"exitoso","idusuario":102}

Comment: Que te devuelve un console.log de data.respuesta? No de data solo, sino del valor de respuesta especificamente